# On the pronunciation of the second derivative

Tags: notation, math-history

I have been looking at Lancelot Hogben's *Mathematics for the Million* (first published in 1936).

In the chapter on calculus he says that the second derivative $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is

> pronounced dee-two-wy-by-dee-eks-two.

The final "two" surprised me as I was taught to say "squared" and I have never heard it pronounced differently.

Assuming that it's not a typo and that Prof Hogben wasn't mistaken, did people really say "two" in those days and does anyone say "two" these days?

I suppose that for higher derivatives just saying the number rather than the power it represents may be easier.

Comment: Well, maybe he meant that $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ is $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx}$ too. ;-)

Comment: i've heard a lot of people saying it this way

Comment: I usually say "the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$" ...

Comment: I say "squared" in the place of the first "two" too: "dee-squared-wy-by-dee-eks-squared". If we can find someone who says "dee-squared-wy-by-dee-eks-two", all $2^2$ possibilities will have been covered.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120504/how-do-you-pronounce-partial-derivatives) there are several ways to pronounce $\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}$, including:

1.) "dee squared wai over dee eks squared"

2.) "the second derivative of y with respect to x"

3.) "dee two wy by dee eks two"

Comment: I did see that post, but I can't see "dee two wy by dee eks two" on there.