# How do you pronounce $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, pronunciation

Just out of curiosity...

I always say "dee-why dee-ex"
Some people say "dee-why by dee-ex" (especially many of my maths lecturers)
Others say "dee-why on/over dee-ex"

I've noticed that most of my maths lecturers never say "$dy$ on $dx$" or "$dy$ over $dx$", not to mention some of my maths teachers in high school said that such a pronunciation is not correct. Is there a reason behind this? Is there a "correct" way to pronounce $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: I use "dee-why,dee-ex".

Comment: Mohammed. Suggestion: Say: deewhy -- dee-ex, you will be fine.:)))

Comment: I myself pronounce it "die-dacks". Similarly for things like $\frac{dz}{dx}$, which is "dezz-dacks", etc.

Comment: "Dee-why **by** Dee Ecks"

Comment: I say "dee-why, dee-ecks". I don't think any of your suggestions are wrong, Mohamed.

Comment: "dee-y dee-x" or "dee dee-x of y" is common I would say, the latter emphasizing $\frac{d}{dx}$ as an operator applied on $y$.

Comment: See also [On the pronunciation of the second derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446488/on-the-pronunciation-of-the-second-derivative).

Comment: Remarkably, in German one pronounces $\frac{ dy}{dx}$ as "de-ypsilon-**nach**-de-iks", whereas $\frac yx$ would be "ypsilon-**durch**-iks"

Comment: One reason not to say "over" is a little Chestnut that comes up on this site a lot: these are not fractions, they just look and behave like they are.

Comment: It reminds me of my childhood struggles with worst kind of mathematics textbooks. When I first read $n! =1\cdot 2\cdots n$ I didn't know how to pronounce $n! $. I used to say "en-dash" in my mind  (sometimes I still do this mentally) and some years later I read the word "factorial". Books should mention the pronunciation of any notation if it is new / unusual.

Comment: I am used to "dee-why *over* dee-ex" but probably just because in Italian it is *de-x-su-de-y*.