# How to say (pronounce) $\partial$ in the context of homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, pronunciation

I am curious what is the common way to say (in English contexts) the name of $\partial$ (the boundary homomorphism) in homology theory. I.e. when giving a talk / speaking.

The boundary homomorphism is $\partial: C_n\to C_{n-1}$ when $(C_\bullet, \partial_\bullet)$ is a chain complex.

Some possibilities I can think of is:

- "Boundary"?
- "Del"?
- "Partial"?
- "Dee"? (it looks like a letter $d$)
- "Delta"?

Thanks for any insights.

I haven't found any answer online despite some searching. [How do you pronounce (partial) derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120504/how-do-you-pronounce-partial-derivatives) is similar in a sense (same symbol $\partial$) but the context is entirely different.

Comment: The first three are all fine. The only important thing is that you're consistent and it's clear what you're referring to.

Comment: Basically what Mike said. I personally say 'del', and I guess the "correct" word is 'boundary'.

Comment: In calculus $\partial f/ \partial x$ is "die $f$ by die $x$".

Comment: Most of the time I say "boundary map". When I am refering to the sign $\partial$, I say "Del".

Comment: @user254665: (i) "die" is hopelessly ambiguous. In particular, the word "die" is not pronounced the same as "dee" in English. (ii) In any case, you have to say "_partial_ dee $f$ by dee $x$".

Comment: @TonyK.  I have heard math profs say  die f by die x.

Comment: @user254665: what, 'die' as in /daɪ/? I can scarcely believe that. What were their native languages?

Comment: die  as in dead. English speakers, Americn and Canadian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience there is no single standard pronunciation, though "del" is probably the most common.  I have heard all of the possibilities you suggest except "delta" used.  If you want to maximize the chance that you will be understood, I would recommend just saying "(the) boundary of" rather than trying to pronounce it as a single word.  In cases where you really want a shorter pronunciation, I think "del" is probably the best choice, but as Mike Miller commented the most important thing is to be consistent and unambiguous.