# Enunciation of $\partial$ as the boundary map

Tags: terminology, homology-cohomology

How is $\partial$ typically pronounced when it is used as the boundary map in homology theory?  The answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110565/del-partial-delta-nabla-correct-enunciation) question provides some good information on the enunciation of $\partial$, but more when it is used as the partial derivative operator.

Saying 'partial' certainly does not seem correct in the context of homology theory.  Is 'del' used in this context?  Perhaps 'boundary'?  I am teaching myself algebraic topology - specifically singular homology - at the moment, but have never heard $\partial$ actually enunciated in this context.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of anything relevant besides "boundary" and "del."

Comment: So given that you haven't heard it enunciated (= spoken clearly), I assume you've heard it pronounced (just not clearly). How did it sound? That might be a first step to shed light on this.

Comment: @gnometorule I have not heard it pronounced either.  Actually, 'enunciate' and 'pronounce' have each other as definitions in at least one dictionary.  But obviously this isn't the place to discuss English.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thanks.  Have you heard 'del' used specifically in this context?  Is it perhaps a generic term for that symbol?

Comment: It is literally pronounced "boundary". For example, the equation $\bdy a = b$ is pronounced "boundary a equals b".