# How do I read out $\frac{∂}{∂x}$?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I read out

$$\frac{d}{dx}$$ as "d by d x".

How do I read out:

$$\frac{∂}{∂x}$$ then?

I saw this [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%82) it said:

> The symbol is referred to as "del" (not to be confused with ∇, also known as "del"), "dee", "partial dee", "partial" (especially in LaTeX), "round d", "curly dee", or "dabba".

So according to this, I should read it out as "del by del x". Is that correct? If not, how else?

Comment: IMO, $\nabla$ is better known as *nabla* (LaTeX \nabla).

Comment: Using "dee dee  x" works for me.  It's often clear from the context whether to interpret "dee" as $d$ or $\partial$.  If not, I say "partial dee dee x".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120504/how-do-you-pronounce-partial-derivatives, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110565/del-partial-delta-nabla-correct-enunciation

Comment: I say (I say, I say) "Partial dee by dee ecks"

Comment: I have edited my answer... check it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say $\displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ as "Partial derivative of y wrt. x" or "del y by del x".

You can also read this introductory text on partial derivatives.
[image]

Comment: Umm you mean "del y by del x" or am I wrong?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Yeah..typo there

Answer (score 1):

Partial derivative with respect to x

Comment: Similarly, I would read $d\over dx$ as "derivative with respect to $x$"